# I get the error "Cannot call methods on nvarchar" why?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

Hi guys I have written this stored procedure but there is an error in it that says

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar

T-SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.User_Announcement_Create
        @Announcement nvarchar(250),
        @UserName nvarchar(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewAnnouncement nvarchar(250)
    SELECT @NewAnnouncement = NULL

    IF( @UserName.dbo.Announcements IS NULL )
       ( SELECT UserName FROM dbo.aspnet_Users
         WHERE @UserName = UserName ) 
       RETURN -1
END

DECLARE @CreateAnnouncement bit

DECLARE @ReturnValue   int
SET @ReturnValue = 0

SELECT @NewAnnouncement = Announcement FROM Announcements

SET @CreateAnnouncement = 1

INSERT INTO Announcements (Announcement, UserName)
VALUES (@Announcement, @UserName)
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem please?

Comment: What is this `IF( @UserName.dbo.Announcements IS NULL )` supposed to do?

Comment: @UserName is not your database server name as your are preceeding the dbo.Announcements  with it. You can not place a nvarchar or any variable in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part

```
IF( @UserName.dbo.Announcements IS NULL ) -- not understandable what are you doing here
```

with this

```
IF( @UserName IS NULL )
```